# Custom Style the Bootstrap Dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have my bootstrap dropdown menu in some Font-color and background-color and while i'm clicking the particular tab the tab background and font color want to be changed and i also want to change the tab background on hover (or) mouseover. I have used some specific styles to change the font-color of particular clicking tab but its color is not changing while i'm hover it.

This is my bootstrap twitter dropdown menu

```
  <a href="#show_tab"  class="dropdown " data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Reviews <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <div class="btn-group" style="display: none;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a href="#tab1">Tasks </a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2"> Tasks1</a</li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" >Task3</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

in this by using the jquery i have shown the dropdown menu

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $("a[href='#show_tab']").on(function(e){
     $(".btn-group").show();
     $(".btn-group").toggleClass('btn-group btn-group open');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use can overwrite your existing bootstrap CSS in your custom CSS file. I think that can solve your problem.

Comment: for hover change you can user :hover with your respective class

Comment: Thanx for ur reply friend i have used some css to change the Tasks font-color as black and background as white when clicking the tab1 but then on hover i changed the background and font-color as white and background blue but the text color is not changing on hover

Comment: Yes i add the css and used the method **:hover** by normal css and eventhough i tried to change the css by jquery too

Comment: See this example it might can help you : http://jsfiddle.net/gv60yh88/

Comment: Or share your CSS here so we can improve it. Thanks

Comment: See this update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gv60yh88/1/ and I believe that it can help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gv60yh88/2/ i already implemented this steps friends in addition to tat i want to change the Tab font-color and background color of this while selecting Tasks(<li><a href="#tab1">Tasks </a></li>)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74551/discussion-between-raja-manickam-and-nimmi).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gv60yh88/3/ hope this will solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks problem solved post that coding as a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".dropdown-menu li").removeClass('activeTabLink');
    var activeAttr = $(this).parent('li').addClass('activeTabLink');
  });
});
```

```css
a.dropdown-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #337AB7;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #0065ac;
}
.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle {
  color: #000;
}
/* Clicked active link color */

.activeTabLink a {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Reviews <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#tab1">Tasks</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#tab2">Tasks1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#tab3">Task3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<div id="tab3">
  <pre>
    content tab3
    content tab3
    content tab3
    content tab3
    content tab3
    content tab3
    content tab3
    content tab3
    </pre>
</div>
```